# sending email with html attachment as pdf using googleapis

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, google-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to send an email with some html code as a pdf file using google apis on node.js, is that possible?

As far as I know, when using gmail.users.messages.send method, I need to add everything to the raw field, including the attachments. The problem is that there's no example about how to add one...

Based on original messages, I've tried using content-type: multipart/mixed and application/pdf. It creates a mail with only a file called noname without any format and having inside the content of the message, not the content that was supposed to be on the file.

I also tried adding the attachment as part of an array, like nodemailer syntax, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages_with_attachments), creating a message with an attachment is like creating any other message, but the process of uploading the file as a multi-part MIME message depends on the programming language.

Here are some examples which might help:

- [Use the Gmail API to Send Emails with Attachments](https://ctrlq.org/code/20132-gmail-api-send-mail-attachments)

```js
function sendEmailWithAttachments() {

  var attachments = ["File_ID_1", "File_ID_2"];

  var message = {
    to: {
      name: "Google Scripts",
      email: "amit@labnol.org"
    },
    from: {
      name: "Amit Agarwal",
      email: "amit@labnol.org"
    },
    body: {
      text: "Mr hänn is schon lang nümme g'she.",
      html: "Mr hänn is schon <b>lang nümme</b> g'she."
    },
    subject: "ctrlq, tech à la carte",
    files: getAttachments_(attachments)
  };

  // Compose Gmail message and send immediately
  callGmailAPI_(message);

}


function callGmailAPI_(message) {

  var payload = createMimeMessage_(message);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=media", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        "Content-Type": "message/rfc822",
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      payload: payload
    });

  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}

// UTF-8 characters in names and subject
function encode_(subject) {
  var enc_subject = Utilities.base64Encode(subject, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  return '=?utf-8?B?' + enc_subject + '?=';
}

// Insert file attachments from Google Drive
function getAttachments_(ids) {
  var att = [];
  for (var i in ids) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ids[i]);
    att.push({
      mimeType: file.getMimeType(),
      fileName: file.getName(),
      bytes: Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes())
    });
  }
  return att;
}

// Create a MIME message that complies with RFC 2822
function createMimeMessage_(msg) {

  var nl = "\n";
  var boundary = "__ctrlq_dot_org__";

  var mimeBody = [

    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "To: " + encode_(msg.to.name) + "<" + msg.to.email + ">",
    "From: " + encode_(msg.from.name) + "<" + msg.from.email + ">",
    "Subject: " + encode_(msg.subject), // takes care of accented characters

    "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=" + boundary + nl,
    "--" + boundary,

    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" + nl,
    Utilities.base64Encode(msg.body.text, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8) + nl,
    "--" + boundary,

    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" + nl,
    Utilities.base64Encode(msg.body.html, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8) + nl

  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < msg.files.length; i++) {

    var attachment = [
      "--" + boundary,
      "Content-Type: " + msg.files[i].mimeType + '; name="' + msg.files[i].fileName + '"',
      'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' + msg.files[i].fileName + '"',
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" + nl,
      msg.files[i].bytes
    ];

    mimeBody.push(attachment.join(nl));

  }

  mimeBody.push("--" + boundary + "--");

  return mimeBody.join(nl);

}
```